# C# (400) Bad Request response received when running code whereas URL works well on web browser

Tags: c#, rest, jira, httpwebresponse, jira-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve the contents of a query from Jira through C# code. I have the URL as **http://jira-server/issues/rest/api/2/search?jql=filter=67355**. When I paste this URL in any web browser, I get all contents in JSON format, whereas when I execute it from code, I get the following exception

**System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

Strangely **http://jira-server/issues/rest/api/2/search?filter=67355**. works in similar ways both on web browser and the code, but the output is not what I expected.

**Here is my code**

```
public class Jira_To_Excel
{
    private const string exec_URL = "http://<jira-server>/issues/rest/api/2/search?filter=67355";
    private string Username;
    private string Password;

    public Jira_To_Excel(string username, string password)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    public void RunQuery(JiraResource resource,string argument = null,string data = null,string method = "GET")
    {
        string url = string.Format("{0}{1}/", exec_URL, resource.ToString());

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = method;

        string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials();
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        string result = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        TryJira.Util.Write_To_File(result,"contents.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("Process completed");
    }

    private string GetEncodedCredentials()
    {
        string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Username, Password);
        byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't my first URL work on the code? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the string created by this line of code: `string url = string.Format("{0}{1}/", exec_URL, resource.ToString());`? You're taking your base url `...search?filter=67355` and appending another element to the end of that, along with a trailing slash.

Comment: Have you tried setting a user agent in your request? Something like Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)

Comment: `the output is not what I expected.` What did you expect? What did you receive?

Comment: @antiduh, Thank you very much, you were spot on, that's the problematic line, I had reused this code from one of our legacy projects, where resource.ToString() was needed to be appended, whereas here, it isn't the case.

Comment: @RodrigoVedovato, I got the bug resolved from my code, but I am curious to know regarding setting the user agent.

Comment: `I got the bug resolved from my code` How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

When you launch URL through code it is not using the same cookies which were used in a working URL via a browser. I spent hours trying to brute force it and tried all kinds of stuff. Basically, it is the same thing if you take this working URL and go to a different browser or private mode and it won't work since you never authenticated there in the first place. In the same way, you would either get a bad or unauthorized request error message.

The solution here is to authenticate using email and the JIRA API token - not password. More info can be found here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Using-Jira-s-REST-API/qaq-p/1231541

Here is my code of how I got it working. If you want to search for new issues only or by whatever status then use this URL for status "New": /rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ProjectName%20AND%20status%20=%20%22New%22&fields=status

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Jira.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string result = "N/A";
            string jiraOrgName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jiraOrgName"].ToString();
            string jiraSearchUrl = "https://" + jiraOrgName + ".atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ProjectName";
            try
            {
                result = PostJsonRequest(jiraSearchUrl);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                result = e.Message.ToString();
            }

            ViewBag.Json = result.ToString();
            return View();
        }

        private static string GetEncodedCredentials()
        {
            string jiraUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jiraUserName"].ToString();
            string jiraApiToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jiraApiToken"].ToString();
            string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", jiraUserName, jiraApiToken);
            byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
        }

        public static string PostJsonRequest(string jiraSearchUrl)
        {
            // Create string to hold JSON response
            string jsonResponse = string.Empty;
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    client.Headers.Set("Authorization", "Basic " + GetEncodedCredentials());
                    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/json");
                    client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                    var response = client.DownloadString(jiraSearchUrl);
                    jsonResponse = response;
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    // Http Error
                    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                    {
                        HttpWebResponse wrsp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                        var statusCode = (int)wrsp.StatusCode;
                        var msg = wrsp.StatusDescription;
                        throw new HttpException(statusCode, msg);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new HttpException(500, ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            return jsonResponse;
        }
    }
}
```